# Ansible running all task even if tags are used

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Here is my tasks with 2 tags

```
- name: Set custom iptables rules
  iptables_raw:
    name: 'iptables_custom_rules'
    rules: '{{ iptables_custom_rules }}'
  tags: 'commonrules'


- name: Set XXX iptable rules
  iptables_raw:
    name: 'iptables_wsg_rules'
    rules: '{{ iptables_wsg_rules }}'
  tags: 'wsgrules'
```

In the iptable.yml file I included role with tag

```
- hosts: iptables
  roles:
    - { role: "Iptables", tags: "commonrules" }
```

It should run only tag with commonrules, but when I run the playbook it runs all the tasks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tags are (de)activated only on the command line of `ansible-playbook` with the [`--tags/--skip-tags` options](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html).
Tags declaration inside playbooks and roles are only to declare the tags that activates those tasks and roles.

> By default ansible runs as if `--tags all` had been specified.

So, if you want to run only the tasks with 'commonrules' tag, you have to:

1. remove the tag from the roles section (or it will apply to all tasks of the role)
2. call ansible-playbook with option `--tags commonrules`

---

If you want to dynamically apply a task, the best way is to use a `when` condition based on a flag that is defined only for the hosts the tasks need to be applied for.

```
- name: Set custom iptables rules
  iptables_raw:
    name: 'iptables_custom_rules'
    rules: '{{ iptables_custom_rules }}'
  when: commonrules | default(False)

- name: Set XXX iptable rules
  iptables_raw:
    name: 'iptables_wsg_rules'
    rules: '{{ iptables_wsg_rules }}'
  when: wsgrules | default(False)
```

Then, in the [`group_vars` or `host_vars` files](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data), something like:

```
# group_vars/common.yml
commonrules: True

# group_vars/wsg.yml
wsgrules: True
```

Or even better, you can even tests the existence of the `iptables_XXX_rules` variable in the when condition, so task will be executed only for hosts that have those variables defined.

Comment: thanks for the information. I have different nodes which has different set of iptable rules, some nodes apply commonrules, some node apply X rules and other node apply Y rules, what is the best way to handle it.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Can I use something like this                                                                          - hosts: iptables
  roles:
     - { role: "Iptables", when: name == 'Set custom iptables rules' } , I am not sure if I say "name" here, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, you cannot use the future task name as a condition. **But** you can call the role with one of the flags: `{ role: iptable, commonrules: True }`

Comment: This is what I am looking for... Thankyou so much :)